# CMD BATs and Capture of Environment vars

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a scripting system driven by powershell which calls BAT files
I want to record the Envs at the end of the BAT session so that they are available for the next BAT file. I have found what I did, did not capture changes from the BAT file...

**More**

I had code like

& cmd.exe "/c $script $optionalArgs & (echo Name^=Value&SET) > ""c:\path\end_envs.csv"""

$script == dosomework.bat
which appeared to work, i.e. the csv file is created with env's BUT does not have the ones created by $script... Rather seem to be the ENVs of the initial cmd.exe call...

After adding the 'echo xx' lines to a BAT file and calling this at the bottom of the bat file referenced in $script, all is OK, I see the env at the end of the $script BAT file

> > Is there a way to fool a cmd.exe /c to consider my extra echo info as part of the called script ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OR...

sae this as $$script.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
(
 echo Name=Value
 CALL $script %*
 SET
)>"c:\path\end_envs.csv"
```

and modify your code to like

```
& cmd.exe "/c $$script $optionalArgs"
```

whee `$$script.bat` may naturally be any name you like.

Note that this assumes that `$script.bat` (the one you are actually executing) does **not** contain a `setlocal` instruction.

---

If `$script` is variable, then in the batchfile `$$script.bat` try

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 echo Name=Value
 set "params=%* "
 CALL %1 %%params:* =%%
 set "params="
 SET
)>"u:\envs.csv"

GOTO :EOF
```

This assumes there are no confounding factors (parameters containing characters to which `cmd` is sensitive, for instance - normal alphameric strings should be fine)

So

- write out the header line
- set `params` to the supplied parameter list + a space
- execute a subroutine *firstparameter* with parameter(s) *remainingparameters*. The `call ...%%params:* =%%` syntax means "the value of `params`, up to and including the first space"
- clear `params`
- list the remining environment variables.

The destination filename is of course up to you. I used a name that's convenient for my system.

So - you would call this script with a parameter of (the first name of the script you want to run) + (any other parameters you require)

Comment: Good answer, this is what I want. I can as per my post and the other, add this to the end of scripts, however I wanted this to be handled by the framework. The problem I see is if you want to call abc.bat with args and the framework bat is doit.bat and I call '& cmd.exe "/c doit.bat abc.bat args"' doesn't the script need to use the %1 arg then all %2* args ?

Comment: Yes. `%*` means "all the arguments to the procedure" so any argument passed to `$$script` will be passed through to `$script`

Comment: hmm can be clarify if $$script.bat is a file of some powershell codeblock ? If a file then it needs to know what BAT to call and arguments to pass. If I call a doit.BAT then %1 will be the script name I want called, wchich means %2 on (the args) need to be passed to the script called inside doit.bat

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would probably be to add

```
(echo Name^=Value
SET) > "c:\path\end_envs.csv"
```

to the end of $script (or at least, force those two lines to be executed just prior to exit)